# Is it possible to delete just images in my gmail inbox?

Tags: gmail, images

I have a lot of automated youtube emails, but I'd like to keep them. However, it is not important to have the images, so I'm wondering if it is possible to tell gmail to delete any images in x label, but keep the text and hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to delete an attached file in gmail without deleting the message thread.

However if these messages only link to YouTube, Gmail will fetch previews to display. If your concern is the storage space, only attached (embedded) images (and other files) will take up your storage space.

To find out for sure, you can use the "Show Original" item in the message's menu. Or just see if the message thread has the "attachment" icon.

To save storage space, you can query for threads with attachments, or even for threads with attachments larger than a given size. (Do a web search for this info.) Then you can delete some of those large threads which will be taking up much of the space.

Comment: this works well if you have this program in google docs : http://www.labnol.org/internet/sort-gmail-by-size/21191/